More complex world creating software in SDF format
I would like to know what are available software products to create and view SDF file. CAD software can create 3D objects, but when creating an SDF file with more 3D Objects, SDF file will be very long and hard to check. Is there any software to validate, check, view and able to add plugins to SDF file?
URDF VSCode extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=smilerobotics.urdf
Unable to find similar extension for SDF.

From How to view .sdf content from within Visual Studio,

I was unable to achieve what I wanted in the Server Explorer Pane, but I could do what I wanted in the SqlLite/Sql Server Compact Toolbox pane. To get this, Tools -> SqlLite/Sql Server Compact Toolbox

Note that there is another linked question of a similar type, how to open *.sdf files?, which suggests using LINQPad.

This SDF is not Gazebo SDF I guess. This is SQL file type. I mean SDF file which is use in Gazebo.

Ah, unfortunately there seems to be (at least) seven different types of SDF file: Structured Data File vs Simulation Description Format vs Server Compact Database File vs Simple Data Format vs Spatial Data File vs Scientific Data Format vs Standard Delay Format. It is Simulation Description Format that is used by Gazebo. One would have thought that the designer could have come up with an original and different name and acronym in order to differentiate the file type used by Gazebo!!!
